# JWT Refresh Token with React-Auth-Kit

Tags: reactjs, authentication, jwt, access-token, refresh-token

I'm creating an authentication system with JWT in the backend and React-Auth-Kit in the frontend (using Typescript). I'm having trouble managing the access token refresh with the refresh token.
Here's the express route:

```
router.post('/refresh-token', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const { refreshToken } = req.body;

    try {
        jwt.verify(refreshToken, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET!, async (err: any, decoded: any) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return res.status(403).send({ message: 'Invalid refresh token' });
            }

            const userId = decoded.userId;
            const user = await User.findById(userId);

            if (!user) return res.status(403).send({ message: 'Invalid refresh token' });

            const accessToken = await generateAccessToken(user);
            res.send({ accessToken });
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).send({ message: 'Internal server error' });
    }
});
```

I'm trying to make a refreshApi as the [official documentation](https://authkit.arkadip.dev/refreshtoken/) recommends, but it doesn't explain it very well and I wanted to know how does it work, how to use it and how to optimize it.

The refreshApi:

```
const refreshApi = createRefresh({

    interval: 15, // minutes
    refreshApiCallback: async ({
        authToken,
        refreshToken,
        authTokenExpireAt,
        refreshTokenExpiresAt
    }) => {
        try {
            const res = await axios.post('.../refresh-token', { refreshToken });

            return {
                isSuccess: true,
                newAuthToken: res.data.accessToken,
                newAuthTokenExpireIn: 15,
            };
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return {
                isSuccess: false,
                newAuthToken: '',
            };
        }
    }
});
```

**Can someone explain it to me? (and in case tell me if I'm doing it wrong )**